# How do I theme the maximized window buttons with Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, themes

I use a custom Gtk theme along with the default Ambiance window controls. Using my theme, the Unity panel shows its very ugly default buttons when my window is maximized. Since I have the same window theme, I am assuming this comes from the Gtk theme. I tried copying and pasting a few things from Ambiance's gtkrc, but nothing has stuck so far.

What must a theme author do to gain pretty looking window buttons in Unity's panel?

Comment: I don't think the gtkrc would affect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dylan, metacity theme support has not been implemented yet in Unity. It's not a priority but someone is working on it ATM. I hope to see it in next unity release (sometime this week).

here is the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/740232

Comment: Is this also relevant for 11.10, or is something different at work?

Comment: @detly The maximized window button theming is still relevant all the way up to 12.04 LTS, at least. Also, just making a general mention here for convenience that this bug is now Fix Released.

Answer (score 0):

Owais is right but there is a work around as long as the theme you want to use matches the default Ambiance window borders.

Backup Ambiance:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/ /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0.bak/
```

Replace Ambiance:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/themes/<yourthemename>/gtk-2.0/ /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/
```

Logout and log back in. As an extra bonus, by "high jacking" the Ambiance theme the login screen is also themed. I have used this with the darker Equinox themes and have had no issue.