# Window controls unthemed when window is maximized 

Tags: unity, panel, window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I theme the maximized window buttons with Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33218/how-do-i-theme-the-maximized-window-buttons-with-unity)

I use `Elementary_unity` theme with customize Control ([Elementary Lion 1.1 Unity](http://dolsilwa.deviantart.com/art/elementary-Lion-1-1-210121746)) and Window Border ([gekos-Leopard-Elementary](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/Themes/Gekos-Leopard-Elementary-Blue-65925.shtml)) and icons Awoken theme.

In the normal window mode (not maximize window), the button layout is as the same as Mac style (red-yellow-green color). However, when click to maximize the window,the button layout has changed (in Ambiance mode).

I want to keep the same as in the normal window (Mac style), and I don't know how to do. See the pictures I captured for easy understanding. Thx for any help!
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwA09.png] [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0aQG.png]

Answer (score 0):

Known bug -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/740232